# Plugin download version not showing in wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

Please help me,
I have hosted my plugin in wordpress.org

https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-html-page-sitemap

This plugin not showing download version . what is wrong in this code

Please check it.

Help me..

Thanks
Review Rights(Pa1)

Comment: Plugin link

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-html-page-sitemap

Comment: Hi! In your other plugin "Frontend posts creator", you've got the same problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove [shortcodes] in Description tag.

WP parsing seems to stop à this moment : The Author and Author URI fields are not considered either.

Comment: Look at this::

https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-sitemap/

This plugin don`t have any issue.

Comment: You're right. Maybe you should move your line `defined('ABSPATH')` after the description tags

Comment: Hi Pierre,

please check my plugin :
https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-html-page-sitemap
I have comment this  "defined('ABSPATH')" line , but till now i facing same issue.

Please check my code and help me.

Comment: Hi Pierre, please check my plugin : plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-html-page-sitemap I have comment this "defined('ABSPATH')" line , but till now i facing same issue. Please check my code and help me.